# Complex TSQL MultiRow Insert with OutPut

Tags: t-sql

I have a temp table as follows

```
DECLARE @InsertedRows TABLE (RevId INT, FooId INT)
```

I also have two other tables

```
Foo(FooId INT, MyData NVarchar(20))
Revisions(RevId INT, CreatedTimeStamp DATETIME)
```

For each row in Foo, I need to a) insert a row into Revisions and b) insert a row into @InsertedRows with the corresponding Id values from Foo and Revisions.

I've tried writing something using the Insert Output Select as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Revisions (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
OUTPUT Inserted.RevId, Foo.FooId INTO @InsertedRows 
SELECT FooId From Foo
```

However, Foo.Id is not allowed in the Output column list. Also, the Id returned in the SELECT isn't inserted into the table, so that's another issue.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please prepare full schema(identity columns/...) and sample data. http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot reference the FROM table in an OUTPUT clause with an INSERT statement. You can only do this with a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement.**

From the MSDN page on the OUTPUT clause (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

> from_table_name Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in
>   the FROM clause of a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement that is used
>   to specify the rows to update or delete.

You can use a MERGE statement to accomplish what you are asking.

In the below example, I changed the tables to be all variable tables so that this could be run as an independent query and I changed the ID columns to IDENTITY columns which increment differently to illustrate the relationship.

The ON clause (1=0) will always evaluate to NOT MATCHED. This means that all records in the USING statement will be used to insert into the target table. Additionally the FROM table in the USING statement will be available to use in the OUTPUT statement.

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (FooId INT IDENTITY(1,1), MyData NVarchar(20))
DECLARE @Revisions TABLE (RevId INT IDENTITY(100,10), CreatedTimeStamp DATETIME)
DECLARE @InsertedRows TABLE (RevId INT, FooId INT)

INSERT INTO @Foo VALUES ('FooData1'), ('FooData2'), ('FooData3')

MERGE @Revisions AS [Revisions]
USING (SELECT FooId FROM @Foo) AS [Foo]
ON (1=0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (CreatedTimeStamp) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
OUTPUT INSERTED.RevId, Foo.FooId INTO @InsertedRows;

SELECT * FROM @Foo
SELECT * FROM @Revisions
SELECT * FROM @InsertedRows
```

Table results from above query

```
@Foo table
+-------+----------+
| FooId |  MyData  |
+-------+----------+
|     1 | FooData1 |
|     2 | FooData2 |
|     3 | FooData3 |
+-------+----------+

@Revisions table
+-------+-------------------------+
| RevId |    CreatedTimeStamp     |
+-------+-------------------------+
|   100 | 2016-03-31 14:48:39.733 |
|   110 | 2016-03-31 14:48:39.733 |
|   120 | 2016-03-31 14:48:39.733 |
+-------+-------------------------+

@InsertedRows table
+-------+-------+
| RevId | FooId |
+-------+-------+
|   100 |     1 |
|   110 |     2 |
|   120 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
```